# Command line in cron job

Tags: shell, cron

i have a simple script like this

```
#!/bin/csh -f
rm -rf aaa
set my_name = ( trucnguyen minhchau ngantran triminhnguyen vuongphan )
foreach file ( $my_name )
        echo "$file" >> name
        echo "loading"
end
echo "DONE"
foreach file ( `cat name` )
        echo `bjobs -u $file >> aaa`
        echo "loading"
end
```

Yes the script can run well in command line.
but when i run it in cron job i realize that it can't run the line. i cat the aaa output and it just blank.

```
`bjobs -u $file >> aaa`
```

at first i though that it can't export the output but the 1st foreach can export the output Name. Can you help me to figure out how to make it run?
my crontab is :

```
21 9 * * * /home/u/duythanhtran/script.csh
```

Comment: Try using the full path to `bjobs`, i.e. `/full/path/to/bjobs -u $file`

Comment: @MarkSetchell hmm idk the path to bjobs. How can i find it? i tried man bjobs but can't find it

Comment: Try `which bjobs` or `type bjobs` or `whereis bjobs`.

Comment: i got the  path to bjobs and try your way but it still doesn't work.
idk what's wrong with the crontab